# How to use @Value in Junit tests

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, properties-file, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to get a property value from my `application-test.yml` file like that :

```java
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class GoogleServiceUtilsTest {
    @Value("${google.service.account.user}")
    private String serviceAccountUser;

    @Value("${google.service.account.path}")
    private String pathFile;

    Set<String> scopesSet = DirectoryScopes.all();
    List<String> scopesList = new ArrayList<String>(scopesSet);

    @Test
    void getCredentialTest() throws GoogleCredentialException {
        // Given
        GoogleCredentials credentials;

        // When
        credentials = GoogleServiceUtils.getCredential(serviceAccountUser, scopesList, pathFile);

        // Then
        assertThat(credentials != null);
        assertThat(new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials));
    }
}
```

but when I use it in my test method, `serviceAccountUser` and `pathFile` variables are always null.

My `application-test.yml` file is located in 'src/test/resources', and tests are in 'src/test/java/' and content :

```
google:
  service:
    account:
      user: ...
      path: ...

# FED credentials
fed:
  url: ...
  token: ...
  grantType: ...

# Logging
logging:
  level:
    root: ...
    org.springframework: ...
```

When I use the `@Value` tag in my app code, all is working. Variables are getting good values from 'src/main/resources/application.yml' file.

After reading comments, I add that the profiles are not useful in my case, but as when I don't use them, it doesn't work, I thought that maybe it came from there and that it is necessary to use them.

I also tried to write the value of the variables hard in the file, and then there is no problem, tests are passing well.

Is someone understanding this problem? Many people seem to have had the same, but I can't find an answer working for me.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: What’s the purpose of the `MockitoExtension`? Also, post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thousands of people use spring boot test and inject values from application yaml, so, we need to see what’s different for you

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar for use `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` tags in other tests

Comment: And for the minimal reproducible example, I know, but I don't know what can I show you more. Maybe the test method?

Comment: Why do you want special profiles for test this way? You can just have applications.yml in src/test/resources anyways...

Comment: @Grekier I agree with you, but I tried it and it didn't work, so I tried to use profiles to verify if the problem wasn't from there.

Comment: A reproducer is not just to show, it’s executable code. You can create a Git gist or upload a zip file containing the reproducer. Like I said, the idea is not new and works, so, there’s no point in speculating.

Comment: What is content of `application-test.yml`/are the properties present?

Comment: @xerx593 `application-test.yml` content this : 

```google:
  service:
    account:
      user: ...
      path: ...

# FED credentials
fed:
  url: ...
  token: ...
  grantType: ...

# Logging
logging:
  level:
    root: ...
    org.springframework: ...```

Comment: You can [edit] your post;)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your test, everything as it's configured should work.  Put your entire test class so we can see exactly which line of the test you expect the values to be populated on.

Comment: I've edited my post @lane.maxwell, maybe it shows the mistakes better?

Comment: @RobinJoseph Just to ask the obvious, but you're certain that the injected values are what's null?  What happens if you add `assertThat(serviceAccountUser != null)` in the very first line of the test?

Comment: My English is not very good so I hope I have explained well, but in my `application-test.yml` file, the variables `google:service:account:user` and `google:service:account:path` have a value of type String, but when I debug my test, I see that the values ​​of `serviceAccountUser` and `pathFile` are null.

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce! (check spelling e.g. "appliaction" :)

Comment: I suspect the mockito extension is creating a new instance that’s not a bean. Without a reproducer, we are really spinning our wheels here

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar That extension doesn't affect this, I can use the test exactly as it's written here and it works as expected.

Comment: @lane.maxwell As written, there are no mocks used in the test at all, so, obviously, there’s more that’s not shown.

Comment: Please check 4.-14. of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config ..these are potential overrides for 3. "config files"...

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Adding the MockitoExtension will have no effect, even if mocks are defined.  I ran this as is and even threw in a Mock complete with InjectMocks to verify.  I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, cannot reproduce!

Having:

1. [Simplest starter](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.5&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo)
2. src/main/resources/application.yml

   ```yaml
   foo:
     bar:
      baz: normal
   ```

   ...and
3. src/test/resources/application-test.yml

   ```yaml
   foo:
     bar:
      baz: test
   ```
4. This test passes:

   ```java
   @SpringBootTest
   @ActiveProfiles("test") // !
   class SomeTest {

     @Value("${foo.bar.baz}")
     String foo;

     @Test
     void testProp() {
      Assertions.assertEquals("test", foo); //!#
     }
   }
   ```

Either `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` has no effect/does no harm.

---

### Whenever you wonder, where your properties come from

Consult:https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

And check (current version):

> ...considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Default properties (specified by setting `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).
> 2. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes. Please note ...
> 3. Config data (such as `application.properties` files).
> 4. A `RandomValuePropertySource` that has properties only in `random.*`.
> 5. OS environment variables.
> 6. Java System properties (`System.getProperties()`).
> 7. JNDI attributes from `java:comp/env`.
> 8. `ServletContext` init parameters.
> 9. `ServletConfig` init parameters.
> 10. Properties from `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
> 11. Command line arguments.
> 12. `properties` attribute on your tests. Available on `@SpringBootTest` and the test annotations for testing a particular slice of your application.
> 13. `@TestPropertySource` annotations on your tests.
> 14. Devtools global settings properties in the `$HOME/.config/spring-boot` directory when devtools is active.
>
> ---
>
> Config data files (3.) are considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Application properties packaged inside your jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 2. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).
> 3. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application.properties` and YAML variants).
> 4. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (`application-{profile}.properties` and YAML variants).

Comment: You’re not using the mockito extension, which I suspect is creating a new instance that’s not a bean

Comment: @xerx593 thank you for trying, I just removed `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` but like you said nothing changes. I work with jdk 17, springboot 2.7.2 and maven, with dependencies from Google API and jacoco, and a few other little ones like lombok. May  this configuration a problem?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I removed it, and nothing changes. When I run my test in debugging mode, step by step, I can see that the value of `serviceAccountUser` and `pathFile` are always null